# Checking if a textbox is empty?

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I have this line of code, that is supposed to prevent the user from inputting a record if the textbox in question is empty.

```
Private Sub Command17_Click()

If Me.Text13.Value = "" Then

Me.Text26.Value = "ENTER A BUY PRICE!"

Else

Dim sc1 As DAO.Recordset
Set sc1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Flips", dbOpenDynaset)

sc1.AddNew
sc1.Fields("ItemID").Value = Me.Combo0.Column(0)
sc1.Fields("BuyPrice").Value = Me.Text13.Value
sc1.Fields("Note").Value = Me.Text18.Value
sc1.Fields("Status").Value = "BOUGHT"
sc1.Update

Me.Flips.Requery

End If

End Sub
```

For whatever reason it does not work, neither the "ENTER A BUT PRICE!" bit or the bit that prevents the record from being input!

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance,

Bob P

Comment: This is what I want to avoid, I don't want users to be able to add a record if the buy price (text13) is null

Comment: `If Len(Me.Text13 & vbNullstring) = 0 Then ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys but I have just found a way round it, I set the default value of the textbox to 0 and then told the code:

```
If me.text13.value = 0 then
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use this piece of code:

```
If  String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.Text13.Value) Then
```

Comment: How can I also make is so that when a user clicks this text box all of the text inside is selected? So they don't have to manually highlight all of the information in the textbox each time they enter information.

Comment: If I've answered your previous question, please mark it as answered. For your highlight question, I think that method TextBox.Select can be used on the event OnClick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
If Len(Me.Text13 & vbNullString) = 0 Then
```